# Looping through files bash script

Tags: bash, unix, cygwin

I am trying to run a simple loop through all files script but it's giving me the following error. The script is called `test.sh` and I am using Cygwin on Windows 7.

My script:

```
#!/bin/bash
FILES = "/bowtie-0.12.7-win32/bowtie-0.12.7/output_635_25bp/*"
for f in $FILES
do
    echo "hello world"
done
```

The error is:

```
./test.sh: line 2: FILES: command not found
./test.sh: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token ``$'do\r''
./test.sh: line 4: ``do
```

Before running the script I converted all the files in folder to unix format using `dos2unix` command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
for f in `ls /bowtie-0.12.7-win32/bowtie-0.12.7/output_635_25bp/*`; do echo "hello world"; done
```

Thanks!

Brandon

Comment: Hmmm... I'm running OSX, so I can't really try it in Cygwin, but pasting that code onto my shell and changing the directory it works for me. Did you also dos2unix your test.sh file?

Answer (score 2):

Collating other folks' answers into a single one.

You've two problems with this script:

- The script still has Windows line endings (that's what the `\r` refers to; it's the character that Windows has in its line endings, but Unix doesn't). [bcarlso](https://stackoverflow.com/users/167925/bcarlso) [pointed that one out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9677203/looping-through-files-bash-script#comment12294313_9677257). Run `dos2unix` over the script to sort it out.
- When assigning variables in a bash script, you cannot have spaces around the `=` sign. [scibuff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1000959/scibuff) [caught that one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9677224/220155).

  The below gets interpreted as trying to run the command `FILES` (which doesn't exist) with the arguments `= "/bowtie..."`.

  ```
  FILES = "/bowtie-0.12.7-win32/bowtie-0.12.7/output_635_25bp/*"
  ```

  Whereas the below is interpreted as assigning `"/bowtie..."` to the variable `FILES`:

  ```
  FILES="/bowtie-0.12.7-win32/bowtie-0.12.7/output_635_25bp/*"
  ```

Comment: Also I would add the [usual warning](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) about parsing `ls` output.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
FILES=/bow.../*
for f in $FILES
do
   echo "hello world"
done
```

i.e. no spaces around ' = '

Comment: It still gives me teh `syntax error near unexpected token $ do\r`

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the find-command

```
for i in `find /bow.../ -type f`
do
  echo "hello world"
done
```

because ls will return directories too.

http://infofreund.de/bash-loop-through-files/

Answer (score 0):

I have same the error:

> ./test.sh: line 2: FILES: command not found
> ./test.sh: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `$'do\r'' ./test.sh: line 4:` do

I fixed it by change the ends line from 'CR LF' to 'LF' on the Cygwin when I run it on the windows